# Firefox setResponseHeader isn't working

Tags: http-headers, firefox-addon

I'm working on a web application where I need to access elements of an iFrame using JavaScript. To do that, the iFrame has to send an "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header to the browser.

Unfortunately this doesn't happen, that's why I'm using an extension to modify the response headers, but for some reason, setResponseHeader doesn't work.

It gets even more confusing since I'm using setResponseHeader to strip X-Frame-Options, but when I'm setting a custom header, it just won't work.

I'm using Firefox's "Inspect Element"'s Network tab to observe the requests, and while it shows the request header being set correctly, it doesn't show the response header.

That's how I'm setting the request and response headers.

```
var chrome = require("chrome");
chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService( chrome.Ci.nsIObserverService ).addObserver({
    observe : function(subject, topic, data) {
            var channel = subject.QueryInterface( chrome.Ci.nsIHttpChannel );
            channel.setRequestHeader("x-mysite-extended", "somedata", false);
    }
},"http-on-modify-request",false);

chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService( chrome.Ci.nsIObserverService ).addObserver({
    observe : function(subject, topic, data) {
            var channel = subject.QueryInterface( chrome.Ci.nsIHttpChannel );
            channel.setResponseHeader("x-mysite-extended", "somedata", false);
    }
},"http-on-examine-response",false);
```

Again, the request header works according to the Network tab. I tried http-on-modify-request to set the response header but that didn't work as well.

That's how I'm stripping of the X-Frame-Options header, which works.

```
let myListener =
{
    observe : function (aSubject, aTopic, aData)
    {
      console.log(aTopic);
        if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response")
        {
            let channel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);

            try
            { // getResponseHeader will throw if the header isn't set

                let hasXFO = channel.getResponseHeader('X-Frame-Options');

                if (hasXFO)
                {
                    // Header found, disable it
                    channel.setResponseHeader('X-Frame-Options', '', false);
                }
            }
            catch (e) {}
        }
    }
}

var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                                .getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(myListener, "http-on-examine-response", false);
```

I've been trying to solve this for two hours now so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding obserer for `http-on-examine-response`, with this you can only `getResponseHeader`

change it to `http-on-modify-request`. then you can `setRequestHeader`, you cant `getResponseHeader` in on modify request though.

This is scrap code but it worked for me:

```
        observe : function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
            // Make sure it is our connection first.
            if (aSubject == channel) {
                //this is our channel
                //alert('is my mine');
                cdxFire.myChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
                if (cdxFire.myChannel.requestMethod == 'GET')   {
                    //alert('its a get so need to removeObserver now');
                    //cdxFire.observerService.removeObserver(modHeaderListener, "http-on-modify-request");
                }
                if (aTopic == 'http-on-modify-request' && cdxFire.myChannel.requestMethod == 'POST') {
                    //can set headers here including cookie
                    try {
                            var xContentLength = httpChannel.getRequestHeader('Content-Length');
                            var xContentType = httpChannel.getRequestHeader('Content-Type');
                            //alert('content length is there so change it up');
                            cdxFire.myChannel.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','',false);
                            cdxFire.myChannel.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',xContentType,false);
                            cdxFire.myChannel.setRequestHeader('Content-Length','',false);
                            cdxFire.myChannel.setRequestHeader('Content-Length',xContentLength,false);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to setRequestHeader, I'm trying to setResponseHeader, actually

Comment: @TheNavigator My guess would be the same, it can be done on modify request, as afterwards it's already been set, try it out. Is the error you get when you try `setRequestHeader` `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE` if thats true then I think my guess is right.

Comment: I get that error when I'm setting responseHeader on http-on-modify-request. There's something weird though. I tried some other snippet of code and it worked but for some reason the Network tab won't show the modified headers. But it works. That's extremely weird.

Comment: O thanks for that note. So setReponseHeader only works in so can you just confirm please: `on-examine-response` only

Comment: thx man. ok so now the setResponseHeader still isnt working huh? try checking sourcecodes here: https://github.com/search?l=javascript&q=nsihttpchannel+setResponseHeader&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Actually it worked :) "There's something weird though. I tried some other snippet of code and it worked but for some reason the Network tab won't show the modified headers. But it works. That's extremely weird."

Comment: That's a good point you made, so the headers arent updating in the network tab. Maybe it's a bug. Can you make a topic at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ and link me :)